# Is UTF a TeXLive standard now?

Tags: unicode, input-encodings, texlive-2020

I'll probably be scolded for this, but I couldn't find an appropriate answer here nor by seraching the internet (perhaps I need another way of phrasing the question).

I use TeXLive 2020 on Debian Testing; I write primarily in Spanish and so I have need of the `inputenc` package to typeset accented characters, as in my name: Óscar. However, upon composing an introduction to LaTeX I accidentally forgot that I hadn't loaded this package and typed as if it had been loaded, and both the DVI and PDF outputs show accents!

I compiled the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\title{Introducción a \LaTeX}
\author{Óscar Guajardo}
\date{}
\maketitle

¡Hola mundo! Esto es \LaTeX, un sistema de composición de documentos; estas páginas son parte de un DVI.


Ça va? È posto! Weierstraß. Łódź.
\end{document}
```

I attach the output below; as you can see, it shows all the "special characters" without having loaded `inputenc`; I wrote the above code on a Bash terminal using `nano`, but the output is reproducible with TeXstudio and TeXmaker.

I am not complaining nor I want a "solution" (since there's no problem, quite the contrary). I'm just so used to loading `inputenc` to write in Spanish that I'd really like to know if it is now unnecessary. Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Yes, it's the default encoding. I think this change was introduced 1 or 2 years ago.

Comment: Yes, it is, since 2018: https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/ltnews28.pdf

Comment: Thank you, both!!